# Why $\operatorname e$ was named e ? What is the history and reason behind it?

Tags: math-history, constants

Why the constant that Euler discovered has symbol $\operatorname e$ and not other symbols? What is the history and reason behind it?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#History

Comment: Contrary to what many would naively guess, it's absolutely not because Euler's name starts with 'e'.

Comment: As the Wikipedia link above says, in the early years $b$ and $c$ were also used. It's just that $a, b, c, d$ are very frequently used for "arbitrary" constants, so $e$ is the first unused letter for a constant (which are conventionally labelled $a, b, c, \dots$ and variables $x, y, z \dots$); in fact in a particular context $e$ may stand for some constant other than the usual one. (Just as $\pi$ may sometimes stand for a function, or permutation, or homotopy group, etc.).

Comment: It's not that Euler "discovered" the base of natural logarithms $e$, but that his choice of symbol eventually become the convention.  See also [Jacob Bernoulli's earlier discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Bernoulli#Discovery_of_the_mathematical_constant_e) of the constant as the limit of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in connection with compounding of interest.

Comment: Retagged. The tag [tag:eulers-constant] refers to [this constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), not [this constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#History).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why did he *[the Swiss mathematician Leonhard Euler $\mathit{(1707–1783)}$]* choose the letter $e$? There is no general consensus. According to one view, Euler chose it because it is the first letter of the word **exponential**. More likely, the choice came to him naturally as the first “unused” letter of the alphabet, since the letters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ frequently appear elsewhere in mathematics. It seems unlikely that Euler chose the letter because it is the initial of his own name, as occasionally has been suggested: he was an extremely modest man . . .

> [— *Eli Maor*, $e$: The Story of a Number (Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press, $1994$)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691141347)

Comment: The paper where the notation is introduced is L. Euler, *De fractionibus continuis dissertatio*, Comment. Acad. Sci. Petrop. 9 (1744), 98–137. (Opera Omnia, Series 1, Vol. 14, 187–216). It was translated as [*An essay on continued fractions*](https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1811/32133/Wyman.pdf), Translated from the Latin by B. F. Wyman and M. F. Wyman, Math. Systems Theory 18 (1985), no. 4, 295–328.